# csscript - catch runtime errors

Tags: c#

I'm using CSScript (www.csscript.net) which works wonderful to easily compile and run scripts. In my case I use the LoadCode method:

```
ClassInstance = CSScript.Evaluator.LoadCode<IRandomInterface>(sometext);
```

I use a try-catch block around this line and I can easily catch/display compiler errors. But what about runtime errors? I there a way to catch them, too?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try wrapping the execution of the script in `try-catch` as well?

Comment: Yeah I did. But in a later region. And I noticed that this works fine. But I think I now understand the basic concept. LoadCode automatically calls the constructor of the class and the runtime errors in there cannot be catched using try-catch around LoadScript. Can I maybe trigger the call of the constructor seperatly?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Are you catching `Exception`, and not a subclass?

Comment: Yeah, I'm catching generic Exception. The exception is showing the following message, when runtime errors occur in the constructor: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry. I found out that I have to handle an TargetInvocationException seperatly. In this case the InnerException included the exception I wanted to catch.